# Output the n most frequent numbers in a frequency table as a list

Tags: python, frequency-table

I made a frequency table to count items from a given list.
Example input: list[1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 8, 8]

`frequencyTable()` returns a dict. of items from the list with their occurence counted.
`printTable()` prints that return. With my example it would be sth. like:

```
1 : 3
8 : 2
2 : 1
0 : 1
```

And lastly (and where I'm stuck) the function `mostFrequentValues()` is supposed to output the n most frequent numbers of the returned frequency table in a list. The return of my example with n = 2 should be [1, 8].
My version returns tuples but I need just a list of the values, without anything else. Since I'm new to Python I did not find any way to filter the rest out yet.

```
def frequencyTable(list):
    freq_table = {}
    for items in list:
        freq_table[items] = list.count(items) 
    return freq_table
def printTable(freq_table):
    for key, value in freq_table.items():
        print(key, ' : ', value)
def mostFrequentValues(freq_table, n):
    most_frequent = Counter(freq_table).most_common(n)
    return most_frequent
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you write these functions, when `Counter` already has all this functionality. is it just for learning ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter in case you wonder what `Counter` is, and where you get it from.

Comment: Yes, it's only for learning purpose (an exercise from a python course to be precise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do list comprehension to return the first element of the tuples:

```
from collections import Counter
def mostFrequentValues(freq_table, n):
    most_frequent = Counter(freq_table).most_common(n)
    return [i[0] for i in most_frequent]
```

Output (with n = 2):

```
[1, 8]
```

Comment: For completeness, you may add the import statement.